# Issue using setAttribute in HTML/CSS File

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

EDIT: CURRENT CODE

```
$(function() {
  flagDictionary = {
    1 : "assets/WCUFOD.png",
    2 : "assets/lesbians.svg",
    3 : "assets/upennLogo.png",
    4 : "assets/bisexual.png",
    5 : "assets/intersex.jpg",
    6 : "assets/asexual.png",
  }
    const time = new Date();
    const day = time.getDay()

    // note that you can use "#MY_ID_HERE" to get an element with     a specific id.
    let mainBanner = $("#banner")
    mainBanner.setAttribute("src", flagDictionary[1]);
});
```

I'm trying to change an image based on the day of the week it is. I've done this in a different file, and it worked fine. However, when I transfer it to a new file, the code completely breaks, and generates an error saying "ERROR: setAttribute cannot read properties of null". Relevant code from HTML:

```
<img src="assets/wcuFOD.png" class="banner" id="banner"></img>
```

Relevant code from the script.js file I am using:

```
    flagDictionary = {
  1 : "assets/WCUFOD.png",
  2 : "assets/lesbians.svg",
  3 : "assets/Gay.svg",
  4 : "assets/bisexual.png",
  5 : "assets/intersex.jpg",
  6 : "assets/asexual.png",
}

const time = new Date()
day = time.getDay()

mainBanner = document.getElementById("banner")
mainBanner.setAttribute("src", flagDictionary[1])
```

And here are my imports for the scripts, in case that makes a difference:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have other code in my script.js file that works fine in the file with the HTML code I am using, so I believe it's strictly an issue with either the attribute function or grabbing the ID.

Comment: `var`,`let` or `const` is missing before `flagDictionary =....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try switching the scripts like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And then wrap everything in script.js with `$(function(){  /* everything here */ });`

This waits for the document to be ready and so elements to be returned.

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    const flags = getFlags();

    const time = new Date();
    const day = time.getDay()

    // note that you can use "#MY_ID_HERE" to get an element with a specific id.
    // we need [0] after we get the banner using jQuery. This way we get access to the plain DOM element that has `setAttribute`
    let mainBanner = $("#banner")[0];
    mainBanner.setAttribute("src", flagDictionary[1]);

    // alternatively to using [0], we can use the jQuery method to setting attributes which is .attr("src", "value") like this:
    $("#banner").attr("src", "flagDictionary[1]);
});
```

---

I suspect that the code that is returning null is returning null because it is running before the DOM is ready. Doing $(function() { /* code to run when DOM is ready */ }); waits for the DOM to load.

Comment: The good news is it no longer errors, the bad news is something still funky is happening. for example, if I set the index to 2 or 3 (which are both files I have yet to update, so they do not exist in my code) the image does not disappear. it still remains as the OG image.

Comment: Ok, good, so we're making progress. To make the image disappear, you can try to set the src to an empty string, like `mainBanner.setAttribute("src", "");`. You can also call hide like this: `mainBanner.hide();`

Comment: We may not actually be, lol, I've just tried to fandangle everything with the formatting again (like you showed) to make it work and I now have this error: " mainBanner.setAttribute is not a function TypeError: mainBanner.setAttribute is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>" the code looks like this:

Comment: (I copy pastaed it to the top of this page so the formatting is not utter garbage)

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're calling setAttribute on a jQuery element. You should be writing `mainBanner.prop('src', INSERT_VALUE)`

Comment: @EmilyMiller My bad, to be able to access `setAttribute` we should have a `[0]` after `$("#banner")` so it's like this `$("#banner")[0]`. Alternatively we can use `attr` jQuery method. I updated my answer.